# Test failure, wrong time with Java and LocalDateTime

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-time, localdatetime

## Good Day!

[mon problème](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtHe2.jpg)

In the test, we must check that the generated rate and the exit time are correctly entered in the database.

[The test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m59LO.png)

[what is important of the class of the test..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7PWt.png)

(I don't why, but i control+K is egal control+Z...)

He say me...

[le problème...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdB7C.jpg)

## A idea?

## Thank you and good luck to you too...

I was waiting green but i have seen red...
I want just "AAAA-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS" without (if possible) don't change all of the programme...

[essaiS faits chacun séparément](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNL2f.png)

without success... I turn around...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to post your code nicely formatted, and very clearly preferably the stack trace from your test failure too. We’d like to have all information in the question itself and not have to follow links. Even better create a [mre] that we can try out for ourselves.

Comment: Please, be aware that [StackOverflow is English only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange/13684#13684). Avoid comments in other languages. Also, being French native myself, I must confess I still wouldn't be able to answer your question even with comments. You need to post some minimal code, without the specific of your parking application, showing the operation you want to do with times.

Comment: You may use [`LocalDateTime.truncatedTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) to get rid of digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Ole V.V: thank you very much! it's green!!! I have no seen "truncated to" in my research but it was the excellent solution! Thank you! Good week! (ah, do you know why my "K" do like the "Z" with control???

Comment: *do you know why my "K" do like the "Z" with control???* In your IDE? No, I don’t know. Which IDE are you using (Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA or something else?)? It can probably be found in the docs and probably also be configured.